# Use VLC (desktop) to play music while phone is plugged in

Tags: usb-connection-mode, music, music-player

Can I use VLC (desktop) to play music while phone is plugged in to my PC via USB?
I have tried to open folder, but when I do, my phone isn't in MyCompter as a compatible device. Is there a plug in or something that will make this work?

Alternatively, is there any media player available that will play the music on my phone through my computer when it is plugged in VIA usb?

Thanks

Comment: You might wish to check our [questions tagged `dlna`](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dlna) for that purpose. [DLNA servers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=79) act as media servers on one device (in your case, the Android device), so DLNA clients can access those media. This way you can use the client on your PC to play music from your Android device. Would that be convenient?

Comment: Are you trying to play music that is stored on your phone, but using VLC which is installed on your PC?
What is the phone in question?

Comment: Yes jonny. That is exactly right. My phone is a nexus 5.

Comment: @Izzy does DLNA work over USB? I thought it had to be WIFI.

Comment: Uh... got me, overlooked that part. No, it doesn't have to be WiFi (an ethernet connection does as well). Not sure if it does via USB, though. What OS you're running on your computer? You could definitely share your storage to it (at least via MTP; on Linux even via ADB), so you could access it with any player on your computer.

Comment: When you say _"my phone isn't in MyCompter as a compatible device"_, do you mean it does show up in My Computer but is not compatible, or it does not show up in my computer at all?

Comment: @izzy im running a mac as well as windows 7. Doesnt work on either. If like it to work on w7 more

Comment: @john yes its listed as a device and i can browse it, but VLC doesnt see it when i go to 'add a folder' to my library or playlist

Comment: What doesn't work: to share the Android devices content (SD card, internal or external)? What Android version? Where's your music stored? You're not using *Google Play Music,* are you (because then your almost lost this way)?

Comment: I am using google play music but ive added my music manually to the virtual sd, its a nexus 5.

Comment: @Frantumn did u try windows media player? Windows media player will list the connected mtp device and you can browse the songs

Comment: On your Windows 7 machine, have you installed USB drivers for your Nexus 5?

Answer (score 3):

Right, I have done some playing around and I think I know the <del>answer</del> problem.

On older Android devices (I'm sure my old Desire HD worked like this), when you connected your device to the PC it showed up as a removable disk and was assigned a drive letter by Windows. The newer devices, including my Nexus 4 and HTC One, show up as a "Portable media device" and are not assigned a drive letter. When you try to add the file to VLC it is looking for a path to this file, however no path actually exists. If you opened the "Music" folder which is located on your device, from within Windows, and double clicked on one of the files, you may notice (I did 'cause my PC is pretty slow these days) Windows actually copies the file onto the PC; I guess to a temp folder somewhere (found the folder: `C:\Users\Jonny Wright\AppData\Local\Temp\WPDNSE\{00000001-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}`), and then plays the file from there.

In short, I don't think its a problem with VLC, or even Windows to be fair. Its the way device makers are allowing you to browse your device from within Windows, and I bet other OSes aswell.

Sorry, I don't think its possible unless you can get your PC to see your device as a "Removable storage" medium and assign it a drive letter.